# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined --- Not using toLowerCase in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gsap

For some reason my animation keeps returning this error when it finishes, however I am not using or referencing `toLowerCase` in my code.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

```
var myStage = this;

//Timeline
var tl = new TimelineMax({repeat:0});

//Mario
tl.from(myStage.backtext, 2, {alpha:0});

tl.from(myStage.marioface, 1.5, {x:"-=400"}, "+=0.5");
tl.from(myStage.hatty, 1, {x:"+=400"}, "-=0.75");
tl.from(myStage.overalls, 1, {x:"-=400"}, "-=1");

tl.from(myStage.sombrero, 1, {x:"+=400"}, "+=1");
tl.from(myStage.poncho, 1, {x:"-=400"}, "-=0.5");

tl.from(myStage.white, 1, {x:"+=400"}, "+=1");
tl.from(myStage.green, 1, {x:"-=400"}, "-=0.5");

tl.from(myStage.whitebg, 2, {alpha:0});



//onmouseover.from(myStage.replay, 0.3, {rotation:"360", repeat:-1, ease: 
//Linear.easeNone});


console.log("animation_done")

//replay
myStage.whitebg.replayBtn.cursor = "pointer";
myStage.whitebg.replayBtn.addEventListener("click", replayFunc);

function replayFunc()
{
alert("working!");
}
```

Comment: Not too sure, but I think it might have something to do with the `TimelineMax` object you are using? Perhaps it is an issue with GreenSock and not your code.

Comment: So comment out some lines and figure out what one is doing it...

Comment: https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-JS/blob/master/src/uncompressed/TweenMax.js

Comment: The error is obviously occurring in TweenMax. The error message should give you a line number, which you can use to look up the issue in the TweenMax code. I can pretty much guarantee you that the issue is `myStage.backtext` or one of the other dom nodes are undefined. You might need to wrap in a `document.ready`

Comment: Click the `<>` and create a [mcve] - also use the uncompressed code to see what fails

Comment: I'm sure it is showing you the error line number in console. Attach the screenshot of the whole error msg.